# Parsley.js error message

Tags: javascript, callback, parsley.js

I am using parsley.js from [http://parsleyjs.org/](http://parsleyjs.org). Wanted to get the error message from the call back function (onFieldError) and place the value inside a twitter bootstrap popover. In order to do so, I'll need to place it inside the data-content attribute of the popover instead of a div. Can any one tell me how to do this or fix this.

```
onFieldError: function ( elem, constraints, ParsleyField ) {}
```

These are the only parameters that are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in parsley.js source file, you'll see that there is an `errors` object config at the bottom of the file that allows you to have control over where you want to put your error messages. Let take a look at it:

```
// specify where parsley error-success classes are set
errors: {
    classHandler: function ( elem, isRadioOrCheckbox ) {}
  , container: function ( elem, isRadioOrCheckbox ) {}
  , errorsWrapper: '<ul></ul>'
  , errorElem: '<li></li>'
}
```

`errors.classHander` is the dom element that would receive `parsley-success` and `parsley-error` classes.
`errors.container` is the dom element where would be appended the error element -> **basically, it should be here your popover dom element** 
`errors.errorsWrapper` and `errors.errorElem` would allow you to customize deeper the error template (by default, ul and lis)

Hope that would help you

Best