# Parsley.js grouping input elements

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

Is there any way to group inputs for validation and display only one error message for all of them? I need something similar to "data-parsley-multiple" for checkboxes and radios.

Comment: Please view my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085202/how-can-i-get-parsley-js-to-oupt-1-error-for-a-group-of-radio-buttons-or-checkbo/22085535?noredirect=1#comment33553577_22085535

Comment: Yes i know that for checkboxes and radios but I need same thing with inputs type="text" and "data-parsley-multiple" is not working.

Comment: Ah. Sorr, I misunderstood. I read that as if you were looking for a way to do it *with* checkboxes and radios. Hmm. I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: This is sadly still relevant in 2018 if your legacy codebases use Parsley

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Currently you'll have to use Parsley events to do so like done in this example: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/events.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly cleverly with a bit of CSS if you use a common error container.

HTML:

```
<div id="error-container" class="parsely-single-error"></div>
<input name="field1" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container" required>
<input name="field2" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container" required>
<input name="field3" data-parsley-errors-container="#error-container" required>
```

CSS:

```
.parsely-single-error .filled ~ .filled {
    display: none;
}
```

---

### Explanation

The CSS reads, "hides any child elements of the error-container that have the class 'filled' and come after another element that has the class 'filled'".  This has the effect of hiding all but the first 'filled' error in the error container.

For reference, the parsely error container looks like this when filled:

```
<div class="parsely-single-error" id="error_container">
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-5">
        <div class="parsley-required">This value is required.</div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block" id="parsley-id-7"></span>
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-9">
        <div class="parsley-required">This value is required.</div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block filled" id="parsley-id-11">
        <div class="parsley-required">This value is required.</div>
    </span>
    <span class="help-block" id="parsley-id-13"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding an "upvote" since this is a far simpler solution than creating your own custom validator or hacking parsley. I find it a huge limitation that Parsley doesn't support out of the box solutions for handling multiple field validations as one