# Parsley not using custom error container for radio button group

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, parsley.js

I am using Parsley JavaScript validation library in a Spring MVC project. I am trying to validate a 'required' radio button group.
I want to display the validation message after the last radio button in the group. To achieve this i am adding data-parsley-errors-container="#element" attribute to the last radio button but Parsley is not using this custom error container. 
The error message wrongly gets displayed after the first radio button. In my case the error container will be added dynamically to the radio button group, but it's not working even when i am adding it inline. 
Please find the JSFiddle sample code here https://jsfiddle.net/8ja2sm98/9/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#commentForm").parsley();
});
 </script>
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label for="gender" class="control-label">Gender</label>                           
      <div class="radio">
          <label><input id="gender1" name="gender" type="radio" value="M" data-parsley-multiple="gender" data-parsley-id="17">Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
        <label><input id="gender2" name="gender" type="radio" value="F" data-parsley-multiple="gender" data-parsley-errors-container="#genderError" required>Female</label>
            </div>
            <span id="genderError" style="background-color:blue;"></span>
  </div>
  <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `data-parsley-errors-container="#genderError"` on the "male" input.

Comment: Hello Marc, yes you are right. Adding data-parsley-errors-container="#genderError" attribute to every radio button in the group correctly displays the validation message in the custom error container. I was following another post here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085202/how-can-i-get-parsley-js-to-oupt-1-error-for-a-group-of-radio-buttons-or-checkbo and i assumed that the attribute only needs to be on the last radio button. Thanks a lot!